# DecodeforHTML and Issues with Excel

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using a `DecodeforHTML` tag, it works when displayed on screen, it nicely formats the word based `VML` language details

When i export to excel, it is empty, once i remove that tag, it works

any clue why it is doing it

Its Lucee

being able to get some help with jquery.table2excel.min.js but it is messing up all columns, i think the code in this plugin which is:

```
var e = this;
            e.template = "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>";
            e.template += "<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions>";
            e.template += "<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>";
            e.tableRows = "";
```

has helped somewhat because that portion is quite a bit in the html code and that is what is breaking the excel if i do it with cf way, is there any way in CF i can skip that

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing your code. Please post a code sample that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Ageax I updated the Question

Comment: Rather than trying to get html code to display in Excel, use CF spreadsheet functions to create spreadsheets that Excel displays properly.

Comment: not possible, the code it is generating in the tabular format is weird and not easy to possibly convert into the query

Comment: Not sure how that javascript relates to DecodeforHTML  or VML...  In order for others to help you, please post a [complete example that demonstrates the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: After decoding to HTML, particularly to an HTML table, you could convert the (HTML) result directly to an Excel sheet. For example, `<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=ExcelDoc.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>record (1,1)</td> 
    <td>record (1,2)</td>
    <td>record (1,3)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>record (2,1)</td> 
    <td>record (2,2)</td>
    <td>record (2,3)</td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: Problem is the VML Tags which are coming from microsoft word, excel seems to be breaking and end up with empty, if i use decode, if i use it as is, it displays those vml tags in there